# On MIT EECS I Accumulator Equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, computer-science, signal-processing

i'm currently studying the dennis freeman's 6.01 from mit ocw. in the lec 3, where the prof. freeman shows a pair of equations for an accumulator that processes signals. [this is it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpxkC.png). there are channels and the initial state, which is "rest", returns $0$ (the delay boxes). i accidentally painted two boxes to blue, don't mind the colors please. the $ R $ below is the rightshift operator which operates on signals.

equation 1:
$$ (1 - R)Y = X$$

equation 2:
$$ Y = (1 + R + {R^2} + {R^3} + ...)X $$

the equation 2 is the declaration of the image, i have shown.

now, from the slide it says: `these  systems  are  equivalent  in  the  sense  that  if  each  is  initially  at  rest,  they  will  produce  identical  outputs  from  the  same  input.` and

$$(1 - R)Y_1 = X_1 \iff Y_2 = (1 + R + {R^2} + {R^3} + ...)X_2 $$

`proof: assume` $ X_2 = X_1: $
$$ Y_2 = (1 + R + {R^2} + {R^3} + ...)X_2 $$
$$     = (1 + R + {R^2} + {R^3} + ...)X_1 $$
$$     = (1 + R + {R^2} + {R^3} + ...)(1 - R)Y_1 $$
$$     = ((1 + R + {R^2} + {R^3} + ...) - (R + R^2 + R^3 + ...))Y_1 $$
$$     = Y_1 $$

`it follows that` $ Y_2 = Y_1 $.

then he proceeds to evaluate the system with synthetic division. i did quite not understand the idea and calculations behind this, can you try to explain in simple terms please?

you can check [the pdf here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/resources/mit6_01scs11_lec03/) [and the course here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CG4ihzTaGdM&list=PL9B24A6A9D5754E70&index=8&t=1596s). thank you.